# Returning Multiple Data in AJAX With jsonencode

Tags: php, html, ajax

The situation is that I have pass the value and have to get 2 values in return. 1st value is an array and the second is a simple string. I get the result for 2nd value that is a string but I am not able to get the first value results individually from the array from the return values.

Code I have used is as

**AJAX Code:**

```
function getprice(dis){
    var roomoccp = $(dis).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin/getroomprice.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { roomoccp: roomoccp },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $(dis).parents(".addroom").find(".roomprice").val(result[0].price);
            alert(result[1]);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Now the Query code that is `getroomprice.php`

```
 <?php
    include "db.php";
    $roomoccp=$_POST['roomoccp'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM room where room_id='".$roomoccp."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $rows = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $p="Second value is";

    $conn->close();
    print json_encode(array($rows,$p));
?>
```

as you can see the 1st value that is returned is an array and I need the value from that array

[image]

This is the table from which the value is fetched in the query.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Your question is not really clear. You talk about two queries, but I only see one

Comment: Your JSON response already _is_ an array containing two items, and you are trying to access both in your JS code already - so what exactly is the _problem_ now? Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: now is it clear what i need?? please see i have edited the question

Comment: check in console what json response you are getting.

Comment: [[{"room_id":"1","room_type_id":"1","room_occupancy":"Single","price":"899","photo":""}],"Second value is"]

Comment: this is the response that i am geeting

Comment: now what i want is price:899

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first array like that.

```
   var data = result[0];
   var count=data.length;
   for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
       var id = data[i].room_id;
       var price = data[i].price;
   }
```